# Prisma migrration issue: saying unkown column datetime_precision

Tags: mysql, docker, raspberry-pi, prisma

I get this following error when I try to run all my prisma migrations to MySQL Docker container on my raspberry pi. I don't have a column named datetime_precision, so this error isn't really helping me finding the source of it. Does anyone ever had this error before when usign prisma/mysql container on a RPI?

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "db_manager" at "192.168.0.196:3306"

Error: Unknown column 'datetime_precision' in 'field list'
   0: sql_migration_connector::flavour::mysql::sql_schema_from_migration_history
             at migration-engine\connectors\sql-migration-connector\src\flavour\mysql.rs:420
   1: migration_core::api::DevDiagnostic
             at migration-engine\core\src\api.rs:108
```

Edit: forgot to mention, when I run prisma migrations to a local container, it works perfectly. Migrations go through with no issue. On the RPI, the database gets created, but no tables are created.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Datetime Precision is not available in versions < 5.6 if you have an older version upgrader to mysql 5.6 or 5.7